# Delete original objects after union boolean?

Tags: modifiers

BH

If one uses a union boolean operator, then (as far as I'm aware) the original object still exists, even after the modifier is applied

If I have many active modifiers in the scene that I don't want to apply, then when exporting it as a glb I would rely on the "apply modifiers" option, but is there a way to remove the original objects automatically? Obviously if I delete them before applying the modifier, it wouldn't work. Even if I make them invisible, they would still be exported

I mainly just want to remove duplicate geometry to only export what's needed

Any ideas?

Blend-exchange link:

[image]

Comment: When you apply a modifier, the underlying geometry is replaced with the result. So you don't end up with superfluous geometry.

Comment: @quellenform I just tested it in version 2.83 and it appears to keep both geometries, especially when exporting to glb

Comment: And you're sure there isn't an object removed from the scene lying around somewhere in your blend file? Have you tried exporting only a selected object after applying the modifier?

Comment: @quellenform yes there are objects there, the point is that I want to export the entire scene, since I have some empties needed for placeholders, but I still want the original objects that have the modifier applied to them to be deleted on export

Comment: OK, without having seen your blend file, I'm afraid it's impossible to find a useful answer to your question. Please be so kind and share it with us: https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Then you export to GLTF you can use different options, try using this gear icon:

[image]

Here you can see options to export only visible objects:

[image]

Or only selected objects:

[image]

You can also put resulted objects in the separate collection and export only it:

[image]